# How to set Restangular URL using params sent by gulp

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp

I am using Restangular to consume my API on the Angular app.

I use gulp to build my angular app before deploying on staging or production.

Each time before deployment, I have to manually change the restangular baseurl:
`Restangular.baseUrl("http://link-to-local-api")`

For staging:
`Restangular.baseUrl("http://link-to-staging-api")`

For production:
`Restangular.baseUrl("http://link-to-prod-api")`

I am looking for a more elegant way to do this and more production specific conditions.

I've read we can achieve this by passing flags in gulp like:

`gulp --production` and so on..

How can I access these flags within my Angular config?

Comment: Its not so much accessing the production flag from angular, rather its a matter of seting up your gulp task. So for example when you pass in the `--prod` flag it might pull in prod.config.js instead of dev.config.js.

Comment: Hmm, okay.
How do I access a config file like that in my angular config, then?

I understand what you're trying to stay, how do I achieve the second part?
Accessing the config file in my angular JS?

Comment: You could put your configs in a service, or a file with only constants for example.

Comment: Alright. 
If you could be more specific or just give me an example, I believe I've found my answer.

Comment: How do you structure your project right now? Is it a bunch of separate files for controllers/diretives etc? If so one of them could be a file of constants. In your other components (eg where you set up restangular). You could import values from this constant file, instead of hardcoding url values, some help along the way: https://gist.github.com/demisx/9605099